# Relationship between the weak law of large numbers and characteristic functions

Tags: probability-theory

I'm trying to learn some probability theory atm and got stuck with the following exercise in Durrett's *Probability: Theory and Examples*:

> **Exercise 3.3.17.** Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots $ be i.i.d. with characteristic function $\varphi$.
>
> 1. If $\varphi'(0) = ia$ and $S_n = X_1 + \dots + X_n$, then $S_n/n\to a $ in probability.
> 2. If $S_n/n\to a$ in probability then $\varphi(t/n)^n\to e^{iat}$ as $n\to \infty$.
> 3. Use 2. and the uniform continuity of $\varphi$ to show that $(\varphi(h)-1)/h \to -ia$ as $h\to 0$. Thus the weak law holds if and only if $\varphi'(0)$ exists.

I would really appreciate some help with the third part of this exercise (I don't quite see the connection between $\varphi(t/n)^n$ and $(\varphi(h)-1)/h$, yet). Thanks for your help! =)

---

*My thoughts on 1, 2*:

I managed to prove 1. using the inequality $\mu\{x\, : \, |x|>u/2\} \le u^{-1} \int_{-u}^u (1-\varphi(t)) \, dt$, where $\mu$ is the pushforward measure of a random variable $X$ and $\varphi$ is its characteristic function. Using the fact that the ch.f. of $S_n/n - a$ is given by $e^{-iat}\varphi(t/n)^n$, this leads to

$$P\left[\left|\frac{S_n}n - a\right| > 2/u \right]\le u^{-1} \int_{-u}^u (1-e^{-iat}\varphi(t/n)^n) \, dt$$

Now 1. implies $\varphi(t/n)^n \to e^{iat}$, so the RHS goes to zero as $n\to \infty$ for every fixed $u$.

2.: Using $|e^{i\epsilon t} - 1| \le 2\epsilon |t|$ for small enough $\epsilon>0$:

\begin{align}
\left|\varphi (t/n)^n - e^{iat}\right| 
&= \left| E\left[e^{iS_n/nt} - e^{iat}\right]\right| \\
&\le E\left|e^{i(S_n/n - a)t} - 1\right| \\
&\le 2 \epsilon |t| + 2P[|S_n/n - a|> \epsilon]
\end{align}

So $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\, \left|\varphi (t/n)^n - e^{iat}\right| \le 2\epsilon |t|$ and since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary (apart from being small) this proves $\varphi(t/n)^n\to e^{iat}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For part 3, the connection is this: take logs.  Using this, you can get that $n (\varphi(t/n)-1) \to iat$: write it as
$$\left(\frac{\varphi(t/n)-1}{\log \varphi(t/n)}\right)( n \log \varphi(t/n))$$
and use the differentiability of $\log z$ at $z=1$ to show that the first factor goes to 1 as $n \to \infty$.

To finish, one needs to work a little harder.  A previous exercise in Durrett shows that if a sequence of random variables converges in distribution, then the corresponding characteristic functions converge uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.  Using this fact in the first part of this problem, we can show that $n (\varphi(t/n)-1) \to iat$ locally uniformly in $t$.  For sufficiently small $h$, we can write $h = t/n$ where $n$ is suitably large and $t$ is close to 1 (or -1, when $h < 0$); I will let you fill in the details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I very much appreciate your help. =)

Comment: You said 'Using this fact in the first part of this problem'. Is this necessary? I think just locally uniformity is implied by the previous exercise in Durrett.

Comment: You are correct, @kayak. Exercise 3.3.13 in the 5th edition.

Comment: I do not understand how this is related to $\varphi'$. Could someone explain it to me?

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, ignore previous comment.  The connection to $\varphi'(0)$ is of course that it would be the limit of $(\varphi(h)-1)/h$ as $h \to 0$ since $\varphi(0)=1$).  Now if we write $h=t/n$ as in my second paragraph, we have $\frac{\varphi(h)-1}{h} = n (\varphi(t/n)-1)/t$, which would be close to $-ia/t$, and $t$ is close to 1.  I still don't see how to get it from uniform continuity alone, though.

Comment: Thanks, now I see: by expressing the derivative as a limit, we get that is finite. But we are missing why is it so because  there is still $t$ to address.

Comment: @Enrico: Fix a large $N$ and suppose $h < 1/N$.  Choose $n \ge N$ such that $h - \frac{1}{n}$ is as small as possible.  Then if we let $t=hn$, what are the upper and lower bounds on $t$?

Comment: @NateEldredge For every fixed $N$ I can find an $n\geq N$ such that $|h-1/n|<\epsilon$. By substituting $t=hn$, I get that $1-\epsilon n<t<1+\epsilon n$. By increasing $N$, $h$ goes to zero and I can always find an $n\geq N$ such that $t$ is close to 1 since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary. Is it right? Is it like a "double" limit?

Comment: You can do better: for fixed $N$ and every $h < 1/N$, you can find $n \ge N$ such that $|h - 1/n| < 1/n^2$.  This gives you $1-1/n < t < 1+1/n$.