# Uniform Convergence of a Function Related to the Characteristic Function of a Random Variable

Tags: probability-theory, uniform-convergence, weak-convergence, uniform-continuity

This question is related to a previous question I asked:
[Using the Uniform Continuity of the Characteristic Function to Show it's Differentiable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2032217/using-the-uniform-continuity-of-the-characteristic-function-to-show-its-differe)

Suppose we have a characteristic function $\varphi$ of i.i.d. $X_{i}$. I know that for all $t$, 
$$
n(\varphi(t/n)-1)\to iat\qquad\qquad\qquad(*)
$$
pointwise as $n\to \infty$. To solve my problem, I need to prove that this convergence is uniform in $t$ in some small compact interval around $1$; say $[1-\delta,1+\delta]$. Using the fact that a family of characteristic functions is equicontinuous, and the fact that $S_{n}/n\to a$ weakly, where $S_{n}=X_{1}+\cdots+X_{n}$, I was able to prove that $(\varphi(t/n))^{n} \to e^{iat}$ uniformly in $t$ on compact sets. I also know that characteristic functions are uniformly continuous. But, I am unsure how to put these pieces together to obtain that the convergence $(*)$ is uniform in $t$ in some compact interval centred at $1$.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I am also open to other ways to solve this problem.