# Calculus with Complex Variables

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I come across the following calculus problem when I am studying probability theory:

Let $\varphi(t):\mathbb R\to \mathbb C$ be a characteristic function of a random variable. (For your reference, this is a bounded and uniformly continuous function which has $\varphi(0)=1$). Assume there is $a\in \mathbb R$ such that 
$$
\varphi(t/n)^n\to e^{iat},\quad \text{for any } t\in\mathbb R. 
$$

Can we conclude that $\varphi'(0)=ia$?

My idea is to take logarithm on both sides. But which branch should I choose? Secondly, how could I use the uniform continuity of $\varphi$ to pass the limit in $n$ to a limit in $h\to 0$?

Answer (score 2):

Since $\phi(0)=1$ and $\phi$ is continuous there is some interval $(-\delta,\delta)$ where $|1-\phi(t)|<1$. There is a continuous logarithm in the disk $|1-z|<1$. So there is a continuous function $l(t)$ (defined at least for $|t|<\delta$) with $l(0)=0$ and $$\phi(t)=e^{l(t)}\quad(|t|<\delta).$$

Now if $t$ is small enough we must have $$\frac{l(t/n)-l(0)}{t/n}=\frac ntl(t/n)\to  ia.$$

*If* you know that $\phi$ is differentiable then $l$ is differentiable and the above shows that $l'(0)=ia$, hence $\phi'(0)=ia$. Does the above actually imply that $l$ is differentiable? This is not immediately clear to me.

**Edit:** I believe the answer is yes, it does follow that $l'(0)$ exists. The [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2593929/lim-ft-n-0-for-every-t-implies-limt-0) I have is not quite trivial - if it's correct then the answer to your question is yes.

Note that if $\phi$ is the characteristic function of $X$, where $\mathbb E[|X|]<\infty$, then yes $\phi$ is differentiable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think perhaps we need to use the fact that the above holds for all sufficiently small $t$'s?

Comment: @ThomasYang I'm not sure what your point is. Yes, the above holds for all sufficiently small $t$, so what?

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I have found a reference for this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123797/relationship-between-the-weak-law-of-large-numbers-and-characteristic-functions

Comment: @ David C. UllrichI have a minor problem with branch cuts. I think we need to choose $\delta$ so that $|a|\delta<\pi$, so that if we use the principal branch, we may conclude $\log(e^{iat})=iat$, right?

Comment: @ThomasYang I suppose...

Answer (score 0):

I have written a solution on my own, inspired by the posts and credit to:@David C. Ullrich

[A classical problem about limit of continuous function at infinity and its connection with Baire Category Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63870/a-classical-problem-about-limit-of-continuous-function-at-infinity-and-its-conne?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Relationship between the weak law of large numbers and characteristic functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123797/relationship-between-the-weak-law-of-large-numbers-and-characteristic-functions)

Taking logarithms on both sides (with the branch $-\pi<\arg z\leq \pi$, and we choose $|t|<\delta$ with $\delta |a|<\pi$), we have
                $n\log \varphi (\frac t n)\to iat$. Since $\log z$ is differentiable at $z=1$, we have
                $$
    n(\varphi(t/n)-1)=\left(\frac{\varphi(t/n)-1}{\log \varphi(t/n)}\right)( n \log \varphi(t/n))\to iat.
    $$
Lastly, we need to bootstrap from the limit in $n$ to a limit in $h\to 0^+$. (By symmetry, the same holds for $h\to 0^-$)
                                Let $\epsilon>0$. The sets
                $$
    E_N:=\left\{t\in [0,\delta]: \sup_{n\geq N}\left|n\left[\varphi\left(\frac t n\right)-1\right]-iat\right|\leq \epsilon\right\}
    $$
                are all closed, by continuity of $\varphi$.

Since for any $t$, the above holds for sufficiently large $N$, we have $[0,\delta]=\cup_N E_N$.

By Baire Category Theorem, there is $N$ such that $E_N$ has nonempty interior. Let $(a,b)\subseteq E_N$, and assume without loss of generality that $0<a<b$. Since $E_N$'s are nested by definition, for all $0<h<\min\{b-a,a/N\}$, there is $n\geq N$ so that $hn\in (a,b)\subseteq E_N\subseteq E_n$, thus
                $$
    \left|\frac{\varphi(h)-1}{h}-ia\right|\leq \epsilon.
    $$