# Convergence in probability and differentiability of characteristic function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems, characteristic-functions

I am trying to prove the following:

If $(X_1+...+X_n)/n \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} m < \infty$ in probability then the characteristic function $\phi$ is differentiable in zero and $\phi'(0)=im$, where $X_1,X_2,...$ are i.i.d. random variables and $\phi$ is the characteristic function of $X_1$.

My strategy is to get a contradiction by using the Levy's continuity theorem in this way:

1. $(X_1+...+X_n)/n \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} m$ in probability and so in distribution to a constant $m$.
2. By Levy's continuity theorem, and the property of the characteristic function of a sum of i.i.d. random variables, $\lim_{n\to\infty} (\phi(t/n))^n = e^{imt}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{imt}{n})^n$.
   (The central term is the characteristic function of a constant random variable equal to $m$).
3. If $\phi'(0)$ is not finite, then I cannot approximate it with a Taylor's polynomial of order 1 around zero: $\phi(t/n)\ne1+\phi'(0)\frac{t}{n}+o(t/n)$,  $o(t)\xrightarrow{t\to0}0$.
4. Concluding, $e^{\phi'(0)t}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\phi'(0)\frac{t}{n})^n \ne\lim_{n\to\infty} (\phi(t/n))^n=e^{imt}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{imt}{n})^n.$

Clearly 4. is not a contradiction: how can I adjust my proof? Is this the right strategy to prove the claim?

Thanks.

Comment: The characteristic function $\phi$ *of what*? Of $X_1$?

Comment: Yes, of $X_1$. I'll edit my post.

Comment: This question is addressed in a theorem on page 565 of Feller's [book](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0270403). The proof is technical and hinges on another theorem on page 555.

Comment: @Gabriel Romon. Thank you for the reference. I read it but I can't understand properly the logic behind it as it's too much short. Would you be patient enough to rephrase it a little bit? Especially, what is the role of $n(\phi(t/n)-1)$ in the proof of Feller. Thanks again.

Comment: Great, thank you!

Comment: Your problem also appears as an exercise in Durrett's book, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123797/relationship-between-the-weak-law-of-large-numbers-and-characteristic-functions) and the associated answers. I don't feel the need to dissect Feller's proof anymore.